# Synchronized SELECT to web sql

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I have need for executing SELECT statement to my web sql table and based on response use result or make AJAX call to obtain results.

It is possible to make synchronized ?

I have function like this:

```
getFile : function( fileName ) {

  var me            = this;

  me.db.transaction( function( tx ) {

         tx.executeSql( "SELECT * FROM content WHERE fileName = '" + fileName + "'", [ ], me.onSuccess, me.onError );
  } );

  // somehow return results as empty array or array with object
  // I know results need to be transformed      
},
```

and later in code want to do something like this:

```
var r = getFile( name );
if ( r.length > 0 ) {
   // use it
}
else {
   // make AJAX call and store it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to create a function with the code you want to execute after the execution of the request, and pass this function in parameter of the getfile function :

```
getFile : function( fileName, success ) {

    var me            = this;

    me.db.transaction( function( tx ) {
            tx.executeSql( "SELECT * FROM content WHERE fileName = '" + fileName + "'", [ ], me.onSuccess, me.onError );
        },
        success
    );

    // somehow return results as empty array or array with object
    // I know results need to be transformed      
});

var r = getFile(
        name,
        function() {
            var r = getFile( name );
            if ( r.length > 0 ) {
               // use it
            }
            else {
               // make AJAX call and store it
            }
        }
);
```

Otherwise, the best way to perform is to use Promises to resolve asynchronous issues but you'll have to use a library like JQuery.
http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/